# Rake FileUtils cp throws Permission Denied

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I am using rake FileUtils to copy a file to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder. I am getting `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:\Windows/system32/drivers/etc/HOSTS`
Command I am using to copy `FileUtils.cp(src_file, dest_file)`. 
I can manually copy and paste file in the windows explorer.

Comment: What are the values of `src_file` and `dest_file`?

Comment: src_file = "C:\hosts"
dest_file = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

Comment: Sounds like you need to execute the script with admin privileges.  Open `cmd.exe` as an administrator and run the script.